# Terraform Kubernetes persistent storage setup no connection made dial tcp error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, persistent-volume-claims

I am getting this error when ever I try to create a persistent claim and volume according this [kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume_claim)

Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims": dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: No connection could
be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I have also tried spooling a azure disk and creating a volume through that outlined here [Persistent Volume using Azure Managed Disk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/persistent_volume)

My terraform kubernetes provider looks like this:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
alias                  = "provider_kubernetes"
host                   = module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.host
username               = module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.username
password               = module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.password
client_certificate     = base64decode(module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
client_key             = base64decode(module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.client_key)
cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.kubernetes-service.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
```

}

I don't believe its even hitting K8 in my RG. Is there something I am missing or maybe I am not understanding how this works to put it together the right way. I have the RG spooled with the K8 resource in the same terraform which creates fine but when it comes to setting up the persistent storage I can't get past the error.

Answer (score 0):

The provider is aliased, so first make sure that all `kubernetes` resources use the correct provider. You have to specify the aliased provider for each resource.

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "current" {
  provider = kubernetes.provider_kubernetes

  # [...]
}
```

Another possibility is, that the `localhost` connection error may be, because there is a pending change to the Kubernetes cluster resource which leads to its return attributes being in known-after-apply state.

Try `terraform plan --target module.kubernetes-service.kube_config` to see if that shows any pending changes to the K8s resource (it presumably depends on). Better, target the Kubernetes cluster resource directly.

If it does, first apply those changes alone: `terraform apply --target module.kubernetes-service.kube_config`, then run a second apply without `--target` like this: `terraform apply`.

If there is no pending change to the cluster resource, check that the module returns correct credentials. Also double check, that the use of base64decode is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Try terraform plan --target module.kubernetes-service.kube_config to see if >that shows any pending changes to the K8s resource (it presumably depends on). >Better, target the Kubernetes cluster resource directly.
>
> If it does, first apply those changes alone: terraform apply --target >module.kubernetes-service.kube_config, then run a second apply without -->target like this: terraform apply.

In my case it was a conflict in the IAM role definition and assignment which caused the problem.  Executing `terraform plan --target module.eks` (module.eks being the module name used in the terraform code) followed by `terraform apply --target module.eks` removed the conflicting role definitions.  From the terraform output I could see which role policy and role was causing the issue.